# continuity and open subset

Tags: real-analysis

> let say  E is a subset of R and f be the real number function o E then
>   f is continuou on E if an only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in E for every
>   open subset $V$ of $R$

what is opn subset V mean? in a continuous function?
I thought open set mean the set contain all its interier points
but what open set mean in he conticuose function

and also what is the closed set mean in continuous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase it to (hopefully) make it more clear.

> Let's say $E\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $f:E\to\Bbb R.$ The following are equivalent:
>
> - The function $f$ is continuous on $E$.
> - For every $V\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $V$ open, we have that $f^{-1}(V)$ is (relatively) open in $E$.

When we talk about $V$ being open, we mean exactly that every point of $V$ is an interior point. (*Every* set contains all its interior points, but open sets don't have any non-interior points.) When we talk about $f^{-1}(V)$ being *relatively* open in $E,$ we mean that there is a set $U$ that is open (in the usual sense) such that $f^{-1}(V)=U\cap E.$

The notation $f^{-1}(V)$ denotes the *preimage* or *inverse image* of the set $V$, and is defined by $$f^{-1}(V):=\{x\in E\mid f(x)\in V\}.$$ Put another way, it is the set of elements of $E$ that $f$ sends to $V$.

Comment: is possible to visualize this concept?

Comment: Which one? Continuity? Openness? Relative openness? Preimage?

Comment: This is a very nice and clear exposition, Cameron. @Kimchi, perhaps it will help you to "visualize" if you consider the sets $E_1 = \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}$ and $E_2 = [-2, 2]$. Let $f_1 : E_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_1(x) = x^2$ and $f_2: E_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_2(x) = x^2$. Try to use Cameron's explanation to find $f_1^{-1}((0,2))$ and $f_2^{-1}((0,2))$. Moreover, both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous. See if you can find open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $f_1^{-1}((0,2)) = U_1 \cap E_1$ and $f_2^{-1}((0,2)) = U_2 \cap E_2$.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f : E \to R$, the notation $f^{-1}(V)$ (for $V \subset R$) is a subset of $E$ defined by
$$
f^{-1}(V) = \{x \in E : f(x) \in V\}.
$$
$f^{-1}(V)$ is a notationally convenient way to describe this set.